# How to change teamname from apple developers team

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

Best all,

I have an account by Apple as "Apple developer".
I want to change the teamname which is visisble within Xcode.
To go to teamname:Xcode>Targets(the name of the app)>General>Identity>"Team".
Over here when I select the team I see an name which is not my name.

1. How can I change the name visible on here?
2. Is this name been used on more places?

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer your second question first. No, this name isn't really used elsewhere--just with your Apple Developer account. If you connect with other team members, they will also see this name.

Now for the first and more important question: Per Apple Developer Support (I called them because I also have this problem), whatever the name on your account was originally when the account was created, that is what your Apple developer name will be forevermore (even if you change your name on your Apple ID). My account was created nearly 15 years ago by one of my parents, so my mother's name is my Apple Developer name (which, obviously, I hate--nothing against my mom). Apple Support was *not* able to change this name for me.

### Here is what you can do:

1. Create a new Apple ID with a different email. As tempting as it might be to use the name of your mom, your dog, your neighbor's cat, or Qui-Gon Jinn, use **your own name**.
2. Sign up for an Apple Developer account
3. Sign into Xcode with the new account

It's not the cleanest or most convenient solution, but it is a solution (and the ***only*** solution, at that).

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.apple.com/support/account/:

> To update the Apple ID and/or email address associated with your account, visit My Apple ID, click "Manage your account", and sign in with your current Apple ID and password.
>
> To update your address, contact information, or organization name, please contact us. Note that certain updates, such as changes to your name or address, must be verified and approved, as this information is associated with contracts between you and Apple. You will be asked to provide documentation that reflects the changes you request.

Comment: apple id name != team name